# Casting unsigned char* to unsigned char** without &

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have this piece of code

```
unsigned char* MemoryPool::GetNext(unsigned char* pBlock)
{
unsigned char** ppChunkHeader = (unsigned char**)pBlock;
return ppChunkHeader[0];
}
```

taken from here http://gamecode4.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/GCC4/Memory/MemoryPool.cpp

I don't know what the cast to unsigned char** from unsigned char* does. If I add these lines of code:

```
unsigned char* MemoryPool::GetNext(unsigned char* pBlock)
{
    unsigned char **ppChunkHeader = (unsigned char**)pBlock;

    printf("ppChunkHeader %p\n", ppChunkHeader);
    printf("pBlock %p\n", pBlock);

    printf("sizeof(unsigned char*) = %i\n", sizeof(unsigned char*));

    printf("ppChunkHeader[0] %p\n", ppChunkHeader[0]);
    printf("&pBlock[0] %p\n", &pBlock[0]);

    printf("ppChunkHeader[0] - &pBlock[0] = %p\n", (ppChunkHeader[0] - &pBlock[0]));

    return ppChunkHeader[0];
}
```

the output is

```
ppChunkHeader 00DCB498
pBlock 00DCB498
sizeof(unsigned char*) = 4
ppChunkHeader[0] 00DCB4A1
&pBlock[0] 00DCB4A1
ppChunkHeader[0] - &pBlock[0] = 00000009
```

I think it's important to mention that, in my code, pBlock points to an array of 9 elements.

Thank you.

Comment: `pointer - pointer` is not a pointer. It has a type of `ptrdiff_t`, for which you should use the `%td` conversion specifier. Currently your program invokes undefined behavior (not only) for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast can't be understood without looking at the next line of code

```
unsigned char** ppChunkHeader = (unsigned char**)pBlock;
return ppChunkHeader[0];
```

pBlock is a block of memory, what the cast and the dereference on the next line do is take the first four bytes of that block, and treat that as another pointer. That second pointer is then returned from the function.

You can see that the cast doesn't change the value of the pointer, ppChunkHeader and pBlock are the same value. What different is how what they are pointing to is interpreted. If you wrote

```
return pBlock[0];
```

that would be just a single char, because pBlock is an unsigned char*. But ppChunkHeader[0] is an unsigned char* because ppChunkHeader is an unsigned char**.

Comment: I thought the question was why not `unsigned char** ppChunkHeader = &pBlock;`?

Comment: More specifically, in the context of the usage within the memory pool manager from Google, the pointer to the "next" block in a block chain is stored at the start of a previous block. The block is just a blob of memory, and you can shove anything in there you want. They chose to use the first N bytes (N being the size of an implementation data pointer) as storage for a pointer to the next block in the "list". (and +1 on the answer).

Comment: @JesseGood Well hopefully the edit to my answer and WhozCraig's comment have explained that.

Comment: I thought the cast was ugly, but maybe that is just my preference.

Comment: @JesseGood I'm not sure what you're saying, how would you have done it without some kind of cast? The code you quoted does not do the same thing.